# Which exchanges, if any, satisfy the following requirements?

Tags: exchanges, api, python

1. Accepts non-US/non-EU citizens (specifically, they must accept South African citizens).
2. Must be a mostly international or US based exchange (like Coinbase or Kraken).
   That is, it's supply and demand must either largely be based in the US or EU.
3. Has an API which supports depositing from bank card ($US) into exchange.
4. Has an API which supports withdrawing(sending) from the exchange/wallet, via email.
   (like this one: https://www.luno.com/en/countries)

   An example of an exchange which meets requirements 1 and 2, but fails 3 and 4 is CEX.io, while an exchange meeting requirements 4, but failing all others would LUNO.com

Comment: can't add the tag 'exchange', no rep...